# Date picker year white background

Tags: jquery

For one of the portal themes I have deployed date picker from http://jqueryui.com/. 
When I click on the text field, calendar appears but the year is displayed in white background. I am thinking this is an image linked in css which is the cause. Any idea where I can change this white background.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried styling select.ui-datepicker-year

Comment: yes, here it is:select.ui-datepicker-year{width:49%}.ui-datepicker table{width:100%;font-size:.9em;border-collapse:collapse;margin:0 0 .4em}

Comment: hard to say without seeing the context.  I don't thinkg jQuery loads in any images through CSS so I would probably look elsewhere. I don't really understand the issue I don't think